# Visual LaTeX editor with citation management

Tags: linux, ubuntu, latex

I need a visual LaTeX editor for *general use* on Ubuntu 14.04+.

To be more specific, some features that would be helpful would include:

- Bibliography/references/inline citation management
- Footnote support
- Figure support
- Image support

Others that are not so important include:

- Spell Check
- Maths equation generation

Comment: Pretty thoroughly answered here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TexMaker may be what you're after. It has plenty of features, including PDFLaTeX options, code completion, basic document templates, error logging, and bibliographic functions.

http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/

It's available in the repos as far as I'm aware, so on Ubuntu it's simply a matter of running `sudo aptitude update && sudo aptitude install texmaker`

If you've not installed the texlive packages you'll need to do that first, a quick (albeint overkill) way of getting all the Texlive packages is `sudo aptitude install texlive-full`

Comment: Full instructions, worth consulting, here: "[How to install “vanilla” TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/46980)" Worked perfectly for me (installing TeXLive 2015 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS).